# device not changing from provisioning to data mode using ESP provisioning

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Hello In the below code I am trying to achieve the device in provisioning mode get the devices near by connecting via ble.
But it is not working as expected .

Can any one help me

```
String bleName =  uri.getQueryParameter(PesConstants.BLE_NAME); // BLE_NAME | for testing
                    String pop = uri.getQueryParameter(PesConstants.POP_NAME);
                    scanDevice(context,"PESPROV_",bleName);
                    BluetoothDevice result = null;
                    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                    Set<BluetoothDevice> devices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
                    if (device1 != null) {
                        for (BluetoothDevice device2 :devices) {
                            if (bleName.equals(device2.getName())) {
                                result = device2;
                                BleDevice mBluetoothDevice1 = new Gson().fromJson(String.valueOf(result), BleDevice.class);
                                pesManager.connectBleDevices(result, device2.getAddress());
                                pesBleDevice.bleDevice = pesManager.getBleDevice(mBluetoothDevice1.getMacAddress());
                                pesBleDevice.connectToBleGattServer(pesBleDevice.bleDevice, context);
                                pesManager.getEspDevice().setProofOfPossession(pop);
                                wifiAccesspointName = uri.getQueryParameter(Constant.SSID);
                                wifiAccesspointPassword = uri.getQueryParameter(Constant.PASS_PHASE);
                                try {
                                    pesManager.provision(wifiAccesspointName, wifiAccesspointPassword);
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        } else {
                            pesManager.initPesDevice(context, bleName);
                            String nonceStr = ""; //uri.getQueryParameter(PesConstants.NONCE); // // stable
                            String provUrl = "";//uri.getQueryParameter(PesConstants.PROVISIONING_URL); // //provision
                            pesManager.sendPesNonce(provUrl, nonceStr);
                            //Timber.tag("PES").i("PesNative-Inside performPesConnectivity method | Completed Executing sendNonce Api Call");
                            checkAPIExecutedTime(loggingData);
                        }
                }
```